# Thread Safety of log4net

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

There seems to be some discussion on whether log4net is thread-safe, the consensus is that the framework is thread-safe, but appenders are not and need to be used correctly to achieve thread-safety. can someone shine some light on this and possibly give example of lets say RollingFileAppender used in a thread-safe way? does it need to be pushed into context? somehow locked, or what?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to this [link](http://www.l4ndash.com/Log4NetMailArchive%2Ftabid%2F70%2Fforumid%2F1%2Fpostid%2F17279%2Fview%2Ftopic%2FDefault.aspx), RollingFileAppender is thread safe (as far as logging is concerned).  This is coming from one of the developers of log4net.  He specifically says that locking like this is **not** required in your code:

```
lock(logger)
{
  logger.Info("Hello!");
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Straight from the [log4net FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#thread-safe):

> **Is log4net thread-safe?**
>
> Yes, log4net is thread-safe.

So, no need for manual locking.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

But I've had a deadlock with ColoredConsoleAppender. And it [sources](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/master/src/Appender/ColoredConsoleAppender.cs) comment states that internal writer (m_consoleOutputWriter) is not thread safe!

```
/// <summary>
/// The console output stream writer to write to
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// <para>
/// This writer is not thread safe.
/// </para>
/// </remarks>
private System.IO.StreamWriter m_consoleOutputWriter = null;
```

And I've switched back to basic ConsoleAppender and have no issues since then.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have two appenders in my config, one of which is Console Appender, and I see it locking up very consistently:

```
PatternLayout consoleLayout = new PatternLayout("%date{HH:mm:ss,fff} [%thread] %-5level %logger – %message%newline");
        var consoleApender = new ConsoleAppender();
        consoleApender.Layout = consoleLayout;
        
        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(consoleApender);

        PatternLayout fileLayout = new PatternLayout("%date{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm: ss,fff} [%thread] %-5level %logger – %message%newline");
        RollingFileAppender rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender();
        rollingFileAppender.AppendToFile = false;
        rollingFileAppender.File = "NetAutomationLog." + DateTime.Now.ToString("yy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss") + ".log"; 
        rollingFileAppender.Layout = fileLayout;
        rollingFileAppender.MaxSizeRollBackups = 5;
        rollingFileAppender.MaximumFileSize = "20MB";
        rollingFileAppender.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size;
        rollingFileAppender.StaticLogFileName = true;
        rollingFileAppender.ActivateOptions();

        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(rollingFileAppender);

        hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.Debug;
        hierarchy.Configured = true;
```