# thread safety of a static class

Tags: c#, multithreading, static-methods

I want to create my own event system in my windows application in c#. To do this, i write the following class:

```
internal class EventManager
{
    private static List<EventRecord> s_listEvents = new List<EventRecord>();

    public static void AddEvent(EventRecord record)
    {
        record.EventDate = DateTime.Now;
        s_listEvents.Add(record);
    }

    public static List<EventRecord> GetRecordsByDate(DateTime date)
    {
        var r = (from l in s_listEvents
                 where l.EventDate >= date
                 select l).ToList<EventRecord>();
        return r;
    }
}
```

I want to be sure that EventManager class is thread-safe. Because i am going to create hundreds of threads at the same time in my application. All the threads will most probably use this class to generate events. And `GetRecordsByDate` function may be called from outside of the class at the time when `AddEvent` function will be called from different threads.
Simply, can you tell me that this design is appropriate for multi-thread windows application? If this is not thread-safe, then how can i make my class or its members thread-safe? Should i use a sync object to lock the whole `EventManager` class or should i use readwritelocker to lock my `s_listEvents` static member?

Comment: Hundreds of threads is not ideal. Threads are relatively expensive even when blocked.

Comment: my application has to collect data from remote machines over tcp. And this collecting operation must be done within a given duration. So i have to create many threads. i may reduce the number of threads by hardware loadbalancing(like using multiple servers) but at all cases, my application will be multi-threaded application.

Comment: Why do you need to create your own event system?

Comment: The following link would be useful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344025/how-to-make-a-class-thread-safe

Comment: @AlexandreVinçon i will add some functionality to event system. thats way i want to control the event logic.

Comment: It sounds like you're going down the "1 thread per connection" model (from your comment re tcp). It is *well known* that this model doesn't scale well.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes i use 1 thread per tcp connection. Actually i use asycn. methods of tcp library and i dont create a thread for every connection but using asycn methods uses thread pool to use threads. i think they are same meaning. what do you prefer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `List<T>`, you should use `ConcurrentBag<T>` instead.

> ConcurrentBag is a thread-safe bag implementation, optimized for scenarios where the same thread will be both producing and consuming data stored in the bag.

More information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx

Also, be careful to create how many thread to access, over 100 threads *would make* slow performance because it takes time for switch context.

*Edit:* For .NET 3.5 you can make thread-safe by using simple `lock`

```
internal class EventManager
{
    private static List<EventRecord> s_listEvents = new List<EventRecord>();
    private static object _syncObject = new object();


    public static void AddEvent(EventRecord record)
    {
        record.EventDate = DateTime.Now;
        lock(_syncObject)
        {
           s_listEvents.Add(record); 
        }

    }

    public static List<EventRecord> GetRecordsByDate(DateTime date)
    {
        lock (_syncObject)
        {
             var r = (from l in s_listEvents
                 where l.EventDate >= date
                 select l).ToList<EventRecord>();

             return r;
        }

    }
}
```

**Edit**:

Depend on your situation, if you read data *very frequently*, use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` with `ReaderWriterLock` would be better for the whole application because it allow multiple threads to read data.

If not, use `lock` which has better performance in general.

See the link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2007/10/07/a-performance-comparison-of-readerwriterlockslim-with-readerwriterlock.aspx

Comment: thank you but ConcurrentBag seems to be not working on .net framework 3.5. since i am using framework 3.5, i can not use ConcurrentBag implementation. Or i should implement this logic on my own.

Comment: @Dmitry which one is ideal, ReaderWriterLock or locking _syncObject object?

Comment: @Fer: ReaderWriterLock does not get much performance on `lock`, use `lock` would be simple and more readable

Answer (score 2):

Since the class is static, you should lock the s_listEvents member. There's probably a big chance that callers won't have access to a shared lock-object unless if you're making the lock available as a static member on the EventManager itself (or any other static class). If this is the case you might as well implement the lock around access to `s_listEvents` in the EventManager directly. This way you avoid the problem with callers forgetting to aquire the lock.

A reader/writerlock seems to be a good choice for this.

Comment: I'm not so sure a ReaderWriter lock is the best choice here. The writers will be very fast, the readers a lot slower. It will need testing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ReaderWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) class:

```
internal class EventManager
{
    static ReaderWriterLock rwl = new ReaderWriterLock();

    private static List<EventRecord> s_listEvents = new List<EventRecord>();

    public static void AddEvent(EventRecord record)
    {
        record.EventDate = DateTime.Now;
        rwl.AcquireWriterLock(0);
        try
        {
            s_listEvents.Add(record);
        }
        finally
        {
            rwl.ReleaseWriterLock();
        }
    }

    public static List<EventRecord> GetRecordsByDate(DateTime date)
    {
        rwl.AcquireReaderLock(0);
        try
        {
            var r = (from l in s_listEvents
                     where l.EventDate >= date
                     select l).ToList<EventRecord>();
            return r;
        }
        finally
        {
            rwl.ReleaseReaderLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following link would be useful:

[How to make a class Thread Safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344025/how-to-make-a-class-thread-safe)

```
private object _lock;

public static void AddEvent(EventRecord record)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        record.EventDate = DateTime.Now;
        s_listEvents.Add(record);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most basic answer to your question is the following: To make your solution threadsafe, you must protect your data storage from simultaneous access. This is done by locking your list at any point in which it is being accessed. This means that when you are iterating over the list, adding to it or removing from it, you must lock that region.

You will probably not want to spawn 100+ threads even though you are accessing that amount of servers, instead you might want to use a thread pool, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y(v=vs.90).aspx for details. Which will give you a pool of threads to use for simple "check in - download data - check out" tasks like the one It seems you are describing.

When writing multi-threaded applications it is important to consider the usage pattern of the underlying storage. If your application will be performing hundreds of adds per second, you might want to consider having a readonly copy of your underlying data structure that you do not block the entire system every time you are trying to get records by date. For a detailed introduction, see [Intel's Optimization Guide](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-guide-for-developing-multithreaded-applications)

Comment: Considering having a readonly copy of the data structure seems nice performance aspect. I will read and think about your suggestions. Thanks.