# Does a singleton injected into controller with non static properties share values between all users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I know about static values, but i am wondering if the same is true for a singleton injected into a controller but the class properties are not static.

Will these values be shared among users of the same application?

```
public class Props
{
    public string SortOrder { get; set; }
    public bool AProperty{ get; set; }
  
}

 public AController(Props props)
    {

        Props = props;
    }

 services.AddSingleton<Props>();
```

Comment: It wouldn't be much of a singleton if it wasn't. It only exists in memory though, so if your question is as to whether it will be shared between multiple instances of your application then no, it won't be shared.

Comment: I mean the actual value set for example ApplicationNumberSorted? If one user sets it to true is it true for all users?

Comment: You have a single instance of `SortingProps`. A single entity in memory. Each place you inject `SortingProps` will receive the same instance, regardless of whose request is being handled.

Answer (score 2):

A Singleton instance is the unique instance within a *single DI Container instance*. But as there is typically only a single DI Container instance in use per running application, it automatically means that that singleton instance, with all its values, is reused by all web requests by all users of the application. It must, therefore, be thread-safe and you must take care not to leak user-specific details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344025/how-to-make-a-class-thread-safe

Comment: thats for a logger though, how would i apply it to my class?

Comment: Make the class immutable.

Comment: doesnt that mean i cannot set one to be true?

Comment: Hi @adminadmin, there are probablty many concepts in programming that you must acquaint yourself with. Try to do some research on what it means for a class to be immutable, how to make them, and what guarantees it gives you.